# Including a page, figure, or equation number in a book citation using BibTeX and IEEE style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran

Does anyone know how to include a page or figure number in a book citation using BibTeX and IEEE style? Specifically using `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`. The [IEEE style manual](http://www.ieee.org/documents/style_manual.pdf) calls for this on page 16, bottom paragraph. Relevant format is in:

> To avoid confusion, rewrite phrases such as “in Fig. 2 of reference [1]” to the IEEE cross-reference notation “in [1, Fig. 2].” Similarly, rewrite phrases such as “in equation (8) of reference [1]” to be [1, eq. (8)]. Other phrases may be rewritten as [1, Sec. IV], [1, Th. 4.2], or [1, Ch. 3].

Note that I would want to be able to cite with a page, figure, or equation number, but also cite the book without any of these.

sample.tex file:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
Here~\cite{hilfer2000applications}, I'd like to see the citation come out as [1, pg. 36]. In this sentence,
here~\cite{hilfer2000applications} I'd just like [1].
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

sample.bib file:

```
@book{hilfer2000applications,
  title={Applications of fractional calculus in physics},
  author={Hilfer, Rudolf and Butzer, PL and Westphal, U and Douglas, J and Schneider, WR and Zaslavsky, G and Nonnemacher, T and Blumen, A and West, B},
  volume={5},
  year={2000},
  publisher={World Scientific}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. How, for example, are you producing 'in Fig. 2 of reference [1]'?

Comment: Thanks Werner, I should have done so at the outset. Example code now in above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One usually does this using the optional argument to `\cite`.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\cite[equation 1]{Andrews99}
\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\end{document}
```

Contents of `test.bib`:

```
@book{Andrews99,
author ="Andrews, G. E. and Askey, R. and Roy, R.",
title  ="Special Functions",
publisher="Cambridge University Press",
year   = "1999"
}
```

[image: cite]